# jquery validation class to element on default message

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

i am using jquery validation to show error messages i was working on the default messages but i want to add a class to the field thats required.

this is what i have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
    required:function (e,element) {
        var error = "<div class='page-controls alert alert-danger messagediv2'><strong>Error! </strong><span>Field "+element+" is required</span>" +
        "<button type='button' class='close' onclick='removeMSG()' aria-label='Close'>" +
        "<span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>" +
        "</button></div>";
        $("button.close").after(error);
        console.log(element);
        element.addClass('alert alert-danger');
    }
  });
});
```

.

```
   $("#modalvalidate").validate({
    errorElement:'div',
    errorClass: 'alert alert-danger',
    validClass: 'alert-success',


    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.insertAfter("button.close");
        error.addClass('messagediv2');
        error.addClass('page-controls');
    }
});
$('#modalvalidate').on('change', function(){
    $(this).validate();
    if ($('#modalvalidate').valid()) {
        $(".messagediv2").remove();
    }
});
```

when i try it out it says

> jquery.validate.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: element.addClass is not a function.  Exception occurred when checking element

what is the right way to do this?

**Edit:** i forgot to say that the class i define in `$('#modalvalidate')` does not display anywhere. And also the class i define `$('#modalvalidate').validate` does make the field red and displays the error message just fine. That just does not work for the default message i define in `jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages`

Comment: Place a debugger inside `errorPlacement` and check what is the value in `error`.

Comment: It already have a .error class

Comment: @MayankPandeyz the class i define at the .validate does not go on the input field i need it to go on infact the whole class is not present

Comment: @Kumar_Vikas i console.logged error (e, i changed the name)  but it just returns true

Comment: @Laurence can you share the code via jsFiddle?

Comment: @Kumar_Vikas give me some time ill work on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you have a DOM or raw JavaScript object as a parameter where you were expecting a jQuery object.

Isn't the `element` parameter the actual DOM element and `error` the error details?

e.g. use `element`:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    element.insertAfter("button.close");
    element.addClass('messagediv2');
    element.addClass('page-controls');
}
```

As generic solution you can wrap parameters in $(). This has no real effect if the parameter is already a jQuery object and will stop it crashing.

e.g.

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    $(error).insertAfter("button.close");
    $(error).addClass('messagediv2');
    $(error).addClass('page-controls');
}
```

or (if the first problem was correct, but still not working):

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    $(element).insertAfter("button.close");
    $(element).addClass('messagediv2');
    $(element).addClass('page-controls');
}
```

Comment: hey i did `console.log(e,element)` this is what i got i do not know if this helps https://gyazo.com/7aff27119e975cfb37e4fce86623e1eb

Comment: i added all of your solutions to `Jquery.extend`and `.validate` but none of them had effect. :(

Comment: And also the normal messages display just fine and make the field red as well it all goes wrong with the default message.

Comment: @Laurence check the third eg there. first parameter inside the function will be the index. So change error to element. as shown in the solution.

Comment: @Kumar_Vikas i changed that the once in `.validate` but it has no effect. And agian for the normal messages it adds those classes but just not for the default message i define in `jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages`.

Comment: @Kumar_Vikas @Gone coding  i got it i ended up filtering out the id if the element that i got returned and used that to `.addClass` sins your answer helped me the most i put that as solution

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#register").validate({
    // your code
    errorClass: 'error help-inline'
});
```

Comment: i already define a errorClass in my `$("#modalvalidate").validate({` but because i edited a default error it does not respond to that